# Pool of warm, reusable Python processes

Tags: python

My application polls an API repeatedly and spawns processes to parse any new data resulting from these calls, conditionally making an API request based on those data. The speed of that turnaround time is critical.

A large bottleneck seems to be related to the setup of the actual spawned processes themselves -- a few module imports and normal instantiation code, which take up to 0.05 seconds on a middling Amazon setup<sup>†</sup>. It seems like what it would be helpful to have a batch of processes with those imports/init code already done<sup>††</sup>, waiting to process results. What is the best approach to create/communicate with a pool (10-20?) of **warm, reusable, and extremely lightweight** processes in Python?

† - yes, I know throwing better hardware at the problem will help, and I'll do that too.

†† - yes, I know doing less will help, and I'm working on making the code as streamlined and minimal as possible

Comment: You make it sound so gross.

Comment: I actually like this quetion's title!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're in for a learning curve here, but `multiprocessing.Pool()` will create a pool of any number of processes you specify.  Use the `initializer=` argument to specify a function each process will run at the start.  Then there are several methods you can use to submit work items to the processes in the pool - read the docs, play with it, and ask questions if you get stuck.

One caution: "extremely lightweight processes" is impossible.  By definition, processes are "heavy".  "How heavy" is up to your operating system, and has approximately nothing to do with the programming language you use.  If you're looking for lightweight, you're looking for threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps instead of "extremely lightweight" I should have said "extremely short-lived". But in both cases, everything is relative.

Comment: But you don't want "short-lived" at all, right? It sure sounds like you want to create each process just once, and have it *persist* to accept new work as new work becomes available. A "batch of processes with those imports/init code already done, waiting to process results" is exactly what `Pool()` will do for you.  If that's not what you want, you should edit the question ;-)

Comment: Right -- the duration of the work they're doing is short-lived, but the processes should be able to do it repeatedly and exist until I'm done with them. You understood be perfectly.